# Where is Firebug installed?

Tags: windows, firefox-addon, firebug

Can someone tell me in which directory path in Windows Firebug is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, open your profile directory. In Firefox go to `Help -> Troubleshooting Information` and click `Open Containing Folder` under `Application Basics`.
2. It will be in the `extensions` folder in a file named `firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi`.
3. This is basically a ZIP file. The files can easily be extracted after renaming the file extension to `.zip`.

Answer (score 1):

It will be in the firefox profile folder. To locate your profile folder, from start menu select Run and  %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ and click Run.

Under the profile folder, you will find extensions and in which firebug xpi file.